# Short Unique Digest in Python

Tags: python

I'd like a way to get a short unique digest for a unique ID from an integer in Python. Preferably 8 bytes.

Comment: "get" **from** where? From an integer? Why not just use the integer directly? Please explain more about what you are doing and why you need "unique IDs".

Answer (score 2):

> a unique ID from an integer in Python

I guess you are talking about some kind of hash.

Why not using the integer itself, if it's within `-2**63` and `2**63`

If you need the integer as 8-byte array:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>q', -2**60)
'\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>>
```